# Is it possible using Geolocation like iOS and Android native geolocation services

Tags: geolocation, mapkit, react-native, google-geolocation

Edited:

I've been trying to use React-Native Geolocation API in my app. The apı the same with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

However, the API is not as good as Android native geolocation services.
When I run the app, my location cannot be found unless I move 40 meters.

I guess also Android applies some [strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) to find the user location.

How to use Geolocation API like iOS and Android native services?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure  if you have tried it already but ,try adding cell tower and or wifi information in the request.

> Why am I getting a very large accuracy radius in my Geolocation
>   response?
>
> If your Geolocation response shows a very high value in the accuracy
>   field, the service may be geolocating based on the request IP, instead
>   of WiFi points or cell towers. This can happen if no cell towers or
>   access points are valid or recognized.
>
> To confirm that this is the issue, set considerIp to false in your
>   request. If the response is a 404, you've confirmed that your
>   wifiAccessPoints and cellTowers objects could not be geolocated.

Check the FAQ section [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#sample-requests) .

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's my fault. The lack of information. Actually I've been developing a cross-platform React-Native app. If I success in using Geolocation -that is the same with navgator.geolocation API in HTML- then I can use the apı both of OS and Android.

Comment: This link should be a good start : http://www.andygup.net/how-accurate-is-html5-geolocation-really-part-2-mobile-web/